# Transform object with multiple value to specific array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having the following object of values:

```js
const data = {
    "generalInfo": [{
            "title": "title1",
            "permalink": "www.link.com",
            "manufacturer": "manufacturer1",
            "category": [{
                "term_id": 35,
                "name": "Motherboard",
                "slug": "motherboard"
            }],
            "img": "https://images-na.ssl-images-test.com/images/asdfIdR/5adf1vELadfZeiMML.jpg",
            "curreny": "$",
            "price": "64.00",
            "availability": "Usually ships in 24 hours",
        },
        {
            "title": "title2",
            "permalink": "www.link.com",
            "manufacturer": "manufacturer2",
            "category": [{
                "term_id": 35,
                "name": "Motherboard",
                "slug": "motherboard"
            }],
            "img": "https://images-na.ssl-images-test.com/images/I/51adfkLhadsfgACH0L.jpg",
            "curreny": "$",
            "price": "59.99",
            "availability": "Usually ships in 24 hours",
        }
    ]
}

// console.log(typeof(data))

var vals = Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
    return data[key]
})

console.log(vals)

// expected output
// [ "1", "title1", "manufacturer1", "64.00", "Usually ships in 24 hours", "", "" ],
// [ "2", "title2", "manufacturer2", "59.99", "Usually ships in 24 hours", "", "" ],
```

I am trying to use `Object.keys(data).map` to create an array structure out of my object. However, I am receiving an array in an array with 2 objects. However, I am looking for the following output:

```
// expected output
// [ "1", "title1", "manufacturer1", "64.00", "Usually ships in 24 hours", "", "" ],
// [ "2", "title2", "manufacturer2", "59.99", "Usually ships in 24 hours", "", "" ],
```

Any suggestions on a way how to transform the array to get the above output?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: where are the `""` coming from?

Comment: The `""` are currently empty spots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want has nothing to do with `Object.keys`. You may use `map` directly on the `generalInfo` key:

```js
const data = {"generalInfo":[{"title":"title1","permalink":"www.link.com","manufacturer":"manufacturer1","category":[{"term_id":35,"name":"Motherboard","slug":"motherboard"}],"img":"https://images-na.ssl-images-test.com/images/asdfIdR/5adf1vELadfZeiMML.jpg","curreny":"$","price":"64.00","availability":"Usually ships in 24 hours"},{"title":"title2","permalink":"www.link.com","manufacturer":"manufacturer2","category":[{"term_id":35,"name":"Motherboard","slug":"motherboard"}],"img":"https://images-na.ssl-images-test.com/images/I/51adfkLhadsfgACH0L.jpg","curreny":"$","price":"59.99","availability":"Usually ships in 24 hours"}]};
let vals = data.generalInfo.map((item, i) => [i + 1, item.title, item.manufacturer, item.price, item.availability])
console.log(vals);
```

I'm not sure what the last two values mean, so have omit them. You can include those similar to what I've done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Object.values()` instead of `Object.keys()` to get the value of each object in the `data.generalInfo` into a new array structure:

```js
const data = {
    "generalInfo": [{
            "title": "title1",
            "permalink": "www.link.com",
            "manufacturer": "manufacturer1",
            "category": [{
                "term_id": 35,
                "name": "Motherboard",
                "slug": "motherboard"
            }],
            "img": "https://images-na.ssl-images-test.com/images/asdfIdR/5adf1vELadfZeiMML.jpg",
            "curreny": "$",
            "price": "64.00",
            "availability": "Usually ships in 24 hours",
        },
        {
            "title": "title2",
            "permalink": "www.link.com",
            "manufacturer": "manufacturer2",
            "category": [{
                "term_id": 35,
                "name": "Motherboard",
                "slug": "motherboard"
            }],
            "img": "https://images-na.ssl-images-test.com/images/I/51adfkLhadsfgACH0L.jpg",
            "curreny": "$",
            "price": "59.99",
            "availability": "Usually ships in 24 hours",
        }
    ]
}

// console.log(typeof(data))

var vals = data.generalInfo.map(function(obj) {
    return Object.values(obj);
})

console.log(vals)

// expected output
// [ "1", "title1", "manufacturer1", "64.00", "Usually ships in 24 hours", "", "" ],
// [ "2", "title2", "manufacturer2", "59.99", "Usually ships in 24 hours", "", "" ],
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array of keys for the wanted order of the items.

```js
var data = { generalInfo: [{ title: "title1", permalink: "www.link.com", manufacturer: "manufacturer1", category: [{ term_id: 35, name: "Motherboard", slug: "motherboard" }], img: "https://images-na.ssl-images-test.com/images/asdfIdR/5adf1vELadfZeiMML.jpg", curreny: "$", price: "64.00", availability: "Usually ships in 24 hours" }, { title: "title2", permalink: "www.link.com", manufacturer: "manufacturer2", category: [{ term_id: 35, name: "Motherboard", slug: "motherboard" }], img: "https://images-na.ssl-images-test.com/images/I/51adfkLhadsfgACH0L.jpg", curreny: "$", price: "59.99", availability: "Usually ships in 24 hours" }] },
    keys = ['title', 'manufacturer', 'price', 'availability'],
    result = data.generalInfo.map((o, i) => [(i + 1).toString(), ...keys.map(k => o[k]), '', '']);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```